# How to get the file size for GET request

Tags: java, servlets

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws Exception{
...
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
if ("POST".equals(req.getMethod()))
{
    long bytesTransferred = request.getContentLength();
    ...
}
else
{
    long bytesTransferred = request.getContentLength();
    ...
}
```

when I send a GET request to get a file, how to get the file size?
I tried using request.getContentLength(), it always return -1. if I use POST to upload a file, it works fine, but still doesn't return the exact file size.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> when I send a GET request to get a file, how to get the file size?

When the server sends a file to the client (assuming the client is a web browser) it "knows" the size of the file because it is writing the content into the OutputStream of the ServletResponse object. When you send the file to the cliet set the size of the file by calling `response.setContentLength(<length>)` in the servlet. This will set the `Content-Length` header of the correponding http response. [Here is the JavaDoc of the setContentLength() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLength%28int%29). Then you can see this size of the file or any content sent to the browser by using the `developer tools` of your favorite browser.

> I tried using request.getContentLength(), it always return -1

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentLength%28%29) is the JavaDoc of the `getContentLength()` method of the ServletRequest class:

> Returns the length, in bytes, of the request body and made available by the input stream, or -1 if the length is not known.

When you send a `POST` request to the server, the request data is sent in the body of the request. So the `getContentLength()` method returns a value corresponding to the length of the data.

But a `GET` request sends the request data appended to the URL of the request as, for example, `param1=paramValue1&param2=paramValue2&...`. That means there is no data in the body of the request. So the method returns -1 as specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you used html form to submit the request, you should declare the method post explicitly, like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="formName"
   action="<url>">
    <input type="file" contenteditable="false" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```